# Anonymous functions: different syntax strange behavior

Tags: clojure

**Why we get nil using fn and NullPointerException using # ??**

```
Clojure 1.8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_91-b14

> ((fn [x] (println x) (println x)) "I have a question")
I have a question
I have a question
=> nil

> (#((println %) (println %)) "I have a question")
I have a question
I have a question
NullPointerException   user/eval1155/fn--1156 (form-init5537026255318038171.clj:1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example: the last statement is the return value of the
function.  The return value of `println` is `nil`.  Therefor you see the
two prints and then from your REPL the return of `nil`.  See below for
a marker, where it happens (imaging an implicit `return` seen in
imperative languages):

```
> ((fn [x] (println x) (println x)) "I have a question")
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Your second example: The body of an anonymous function is directly
called.  You should add a `do` inside the anon fn.  Otherwise (as in
your example), This will use the result of the first print as a function
to call; add `do` at marker:

```
> (#((println %) (println %)) "I have a question")
     ^
```

You can see this unfold, if you check the resulting code after the
reader does its magic (see marker again):

```
user=> '(#((println %) (println %)) "I have a question")
((fn* [p1__8265#] ((println p1__8265#) (println p1__8265#))) "I have a question")
                   ^
```